# Degree of a generically finite map

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, at.algebraic-topology

I have a rational map  $f:\mathbb C^n\longrightarrow \mathbb C^n,$ all I know $f$ is defined by homogenious polynomials of degree $m$ and $f$ not necessarily a morphism. Computer packages aside, I am wondering if the passonate algebraic geometers have a general scheme of computing $\deg f$  explicitly?

Comment: What do you mean by $\ker f$?

Comment: If the map is generically finite, I think the degree is $m^n$. It certainly is that for "most" $f$. 

Comment: @ Felipe it seems like that is true if $f$ is a morphism never true in general. 

Comment: @Felipe for $\ker f\neq 0$ I only wanted to say $f$ is not a morphism, fixed it now.

Comment: If $f$ is not a morphism, what does "defined by polynomials" mean?

Comment: Example $n=3,$ $f$ consinder something like $(a,b,c)\longmapsto(ab-2c^2,7ac, c^2+8ab).$

Comment: @Ongaro: The example you have written down is indeed a morphism (it is defined everywhere). For a rational map not to be a morphism it needs to contain expressions which are rational functions (i.e. quotients of polynomials). What does your rational map look like? Is it made up of rational functions or polynomials?

Comment: @Daniel,that was just an example to answer "defined by polynomials". To me such a map is a morphism if the polynomials have no common root and I get an induced map $\mathbb P^{n−1}\longrightarrow \mathbb P^{n−1}$. 

Comment: So you actually have a rational map from projective space to itself and you want to know the degree of this map? As Felipe asks, do you know that if map is generically finite? The degree will not be defined if every fibre is infinite.

Comment: I have checked finiteness genericall by calculating the inverse image at a point.

Answer (score 3):

An upper estimate can be obtained from Proposition 1.1 in the following paper:

Rusek, Kamil; Winiarski, Tadeusz
Polynomial automorphisms of $\mathbb{C}^n$.
Univ. Iagel. Acta Math. No. 24 (1984), 143–149

http://www2.im.uj.edu.pl/actamath/PDF/24-143-149.pdf

Let $F=(F_1,...,F_n):\mathbb{C}^n \mapsto \mathbb{C}^n$, where $F_1,...,F_n$ are polynomials  (none of them identically zero). Assume that  $F^{-1}(0)=\{a_1,...a_k\}$. Then $\nu_F:= \sum_i m_{a_i}F \leq {\rm deg }F_1\cdot ...\cdot {\rm deg }F_n$, where $m_{a_i}F$ is the multiplicity of $F$ at the point $a_i$.

Note that the polynomials in the proposition are not necessarily homogeneous. The assumption that $F^{-1}(0)$ be finite ensures that the multiplicities are well defined.